# Slow docker container

Tags: docker

I am using dockerfile containers provided by Newscoop and containers appear to be really slow for me (https://github.com/sourcefabric/Newscoop). I do not believe it is mySQL image causing the problem, instead it seems like mounted cache and log folders are the ones to blame. There are a lot read/writes happening from those files that are mounted, and this, I believe, slows down the whole thing.

Is there a way to force specific folder to not be mounted? Or is there another obvious cause of this slowdown?

Those are the lines I blame:

```
newscoop:
    build: ../
    command: newscoop
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - ../newscoop:/var/www/newscoop
```

Comment: try `docker top your_container` and maybe `docker logs yourcontainer` will show some relevant information

Comment: Thank you for the reponse. MySQL container has only mysql process running while the container running apache has 11 '/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start' processes, one tail -f of the log file and cron start. 11 apache processes look a bit suspisious to me